# Retrieve unique column names over multiple DataFrames and append all to a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop, append

**Description of task**

I am wanting to retrieve the column names across multiple DataFrames and append the unique names to a list. The following code appends the first column names to a list, but I am not sure how to retrieve and append the different column names of the remaining DataFrames to `desiredlist`. Any ideas would be awesome!

```
alldf = [df, df1, df2, df3, df4]

for index, dataframe in enumerate(alldf):
    desiredlist = []
    a = dataframe.columns.values.tolist()
    desiredlist.append(a)
```

**Example of DataFrames**

```
  df

       ID    AA  TA  TL
Date                      
2001  a   1.0  44  50 

df1

       ID    AA  TM  TP
Date                      
2001  a   1.0  44  50 

df2

       ID    TP  TZ  TK
Date                      
2001  a   1.0  44  50 

df3

       ID    AA  TA  TG
Date                      
2001  a   1.0  44  50 

df4

       ID    AB  TT  TQ
Date                      
2001  a   1.0  44  50
```

**List Output Desired**

All column names output across multiple DataFrames, but only appearing once

```
desiredlist = ['AA', 'TA', 'TL', 'TM', 'TP', 'TZ', 'TK','TG', 'AB', 'TT', 'TQ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the list "a" and add values that haven't already been added to "desiredlist".
I think this is what you were going for.

```
alldf = [df, df1, df2, df3, df4]
desiredlist = []
for index, dataframe in enumerate(alldf):

    a = dataframe.columns.values.tolist()
    for column_name in a:
        if not column_name in desiredlist:
            desiredlist.append(column_name)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps mate! Does the job perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) to populate set and then get unique column names.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1], 'B':[2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1], 'C':[2]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'D':[1], 'E':[2]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'D':[1], 'B':[2]})

unique = set()
for d in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
    unique.update(d)
print(unique)
```

Prints:

```
{'A', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'B'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does the job too! Cheers :)